# ASPNET Core 5.0 is not showing in selection box:Visual Studio 2019 16.6

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I have .net 5.0 preview 4 sdk installed. I have VS 2019 pro 16.6. Yet, I do not see .net5 in the selection box. Manually changing the target version in the project will not work either. Anybody has any idea?. In older VS versions, we use to have a selection possibility in the Options menu, if we wanted to include preview versions in the selection box. The newer VS does not have this selection possibility either.

Comment: I think you should  install `.NET 5.0 Preview 1 SDK`, more details, you could refer to this : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-net-5-0/

Comment: @Yongqing: Other than the sdk version number, it is the same thing as what I did. One would not get stuck with the preview 1 version of course. As new SDK versions come out, the VS should be able to take them up easily, once you install them. That is the proper way of handling new versions of the sdks. . Perhaps I need to remove the sdk  and reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

You must install VS 16.7 Preview. I know the release notes and blog post for .Net 5.0 Preview 4 say otherwise, but this was the only way for me to get things going.